# Ubuntu Server can’t connect to Wifi

Tags: wifi, ubuntu, setup

I flashed my raspberry pi with [ARM server ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/server/arm) but I can’t get my pi to connect to the wifi. I was following [this](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/connect-wifi-terminal-ubuntu-16-04/) tutorial, which instructs me to use `ifconfig`, but my pi is telling me that it doesn’t come preinstalled with `ifconfig`.

Is someone aware of other ways to connect my pi to wifi? I’ve also tried connecting directly through an ethernet cable, but that doesn’t seem to be working either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifconfig` has been removed, in favor of `ip`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145449/361960

Ubuntu Server is different from Ubuntu Desktop: Ubuntu Server uses [Netplan](https://netplan.io/) to manage the network connections.

Here's a guide on how to connect to WiFi using Netplan: [https://tttapa.github.io/Pages/Raspberry-Pi/Installation+Setup/WiFi-Setup.html](https://tttapa.github.io/Pages/Raspberry-Pi/Installation+Setup/WiFi-Setup.html#disabling-cloud-init)

I've never tried running the ARM version of Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi, you might want to use the specific Ubuntu Server Raspberry Pi version instead: https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

Comment: got a rather cryptic error running sudo netplan apply: `[ 2846.098947 ] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_add_iface: iface validation failed: err=-16`, sorting out what that means now

Comment: Apparently the wifi is connected now though, so maybe I’m good?

Comment: @7l-l04 that error might be because you're not using the Raspberry Pi version of Ubuntu.